# Dialogue puts invention into public domain

Tags: ownership

**Background**

I worked for a US based defense contractor.

Because the parent firm was British, the division had to be incorporated with it's own board of directors so as to create a fire wall on what we were doing from the foreign entity that owned us.

We were also separate from the approximately 36 other divisions.

During my employment, I came up with a novel invention.

Although this Proprietary Agreement states 42 times the agreement is between myself and the Incorporated Division, Corporate is now claiming the agreement extends to all divisions.  I have nothing in writing that states as such from my time of employment.

**Question:** By disclosing the invention to an engineer from a division other than the solely Incorporated Div I work for, did I put the invention into public domain?

Dialogue occurred around summer of 2012.